# Why does the method add() does not increase the size of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a manual program that will increase the array size dynamically. But it always through the out of bound exception. I don't know why.
Any help is appreciated!

```
public class variable_arrays_no_list_use {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 2;
    int []arr = new int[size];
    arr = add(arr, 5);
    arr = add(arr, 6);
    arr = add(arr, 7);

    
}

public static int lastindex = -1; //last index variable

public static int [] add(int []array,int value)
{
    
    if (array.length == lastindex+1) {
        int []tempa = new int[lastindex*2];

        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            tempa[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = tempa;

    }
        array[++lastindex] = value;
        return array;
}}
```

error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
> at variable_arrays_no_list_use.add(variable_arrays_no_list_use.java:28)
> at variable_arrays_no_list_use.main(variable_arrays_no_list_use.java:8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this part:

```
if (array.length == lastindex+1) {
    int []tempa = new int[lastindex*2];
```

Here, when you add the third element, `lastindex` has the value of 1, `array.length` is 2, and in the if, the condition is true because `2 == 1+1`. However, to calculate the new size of the new array then, you take the value of `lastindex`, which is still 1, so the new array again gets the size 2. What you want to do, is the following:

```
if (array.length == lastindex+1) {
    int []tempa = new int[(lastindex+1)*2];
```